# Get Day For Previous Month

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a what seems like simple date issue and I just can't wrap my head around trying to get it efficiently... I basically need to get the previous months date for a specific day.

**For example**: If today is the 3rd Thursday of the month, I want to get the 3rd Thursday's date of last month. Its important that its based of the number of the day...ie: First Monday, 4th Friday, 2nd Wednesday, etc.

What's the best way to get this done?

BTW...If there is not an equivalent previous months day that is fine. I can handle that. Also, currently I am counting the number or days ("Mondays", "Tuesdays", etc) manually to figure this out. I was just hoping there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: So what happens when there isn't one?  It's very often that there might be a 4th Friday of this month, but there is no 4th Friday of last month.  Also if you're worried about the day, what happens for the 31st when last month only has 30 days (or 29/28)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Even if you should count it one-by-one you won't even notice the algorithm consumes any CPU time, so no worries about performance of efficiency.

Comment: @DJKraze, Yes and I have checked with google, but I couldn't find anything useful in this scenario. I can get this done by counting up the days of the (ie: counting the mondays before I hit my monday), but i have a feeling there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @Erik I think you mean `there might not be a FIFTH day of last month`.  Every month will have a 4th, since every month has at least 28 days =)

Comment: @saluce yeah thats what I meant!

Comment: @ErikPhillips - good point, but thats why I need to know if its the first thursday, second thursday, etc. of the month. There won't be alot of days without an equivelent previous month counter part. If there isn't an equivelent, that is fine...then there just isn't. Nullable dateime or something like that should work out.

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny - Yea, counting them up is how I worked it out (by counting out the number of days). I find that many times with date time there are ways to do things that are not so obvious that are more elegant and cleaner than the most obvious method of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
static DateTime? GetLastMonthSameNthDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    int nth = (date.Day-1) / 7; // returns 0 if 1st, 1 if 2nd...
    var prevMonthDay = date.AddMonths(-1);

    // find the first date of month having the same day of week
    var d = new DateTime(prevMonthDay.Year, prevMonthDay.Month, 1);
    while(d.Day <= 7)
    {
        if (d.DayOfWeek == date.DayOfWeek)
            break;
        d = d.AddDays(1);
    }
    // go to nth day of week
    d = d.AddDays(7 * nth);
    // if we have passed the current month, there's no nth day of week
    if (d.Month != prevMonthDay.Month)
        return null;
    return d;
}
```

Usage example:

```
// 3rd wednesday of August 2012
var a = new DateTime(2012, 8, 15);
var aPrev = GetLastMonthSameNthDayOfWeek(a);
// aPrev = July 18th 2012 (i.e. the 3rd wednesday of July 2012)

// 5th wednesday of August 2012
var b = new DateTime(2012, 8, 15);
var bPrev = GetLastMonthSameNthDayOfWeek(b);
// bPrev = null, because there's no 5th wednesday of July 2012
```

N.B. :

getting the ordinal position of the day of week inside a month is really easy:

```
int nth = ((date.Day-1) / 7) + 1; // 1 -> 1st, 2 -> 2nd, 3 -> 3rd ...
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... thanks. So much cleaner than how I was doing it. I wish I could accept the answer more than once.

Comment: @AGoodDisplayName: there was a little bug (concerning the days multiple of 7), please check the edited code ;)

Answer (score 1):

As I couldn't find a built-in way, I've written this simple extension method for `DateTime`, check it out:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static DateTime GetPositionalDate(this DateTime BaseDate, DayOfWeek WeekDay, int position)
    {
        if (position < 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid position");
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime ReturnDate = new DateTime(BaseDate.Year, BaseDate.Month, BaseDate.Day);
            int PositionControl = 1;
            bool FoundDate = false;

            while(ReturnDate.DayOfWeek != WeekDay)
            {
                ReturnDate = ReturnDate.AddDays(1);
            }

            while (!FoundDate && PositionControl <= position)
            {
                PositionControl++;

                if (PositionControl == position)
                {
                    FoundDate = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ReturnDate = ReturnDate.AddDays(7);
                }
            }

            if (FoundDate)
            {
                return ReturnDate;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Date not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime lastMonth = DateTime.Now.GetPositionalDate(DayOfWeek.Sunday, 2);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no, by default, a way that .Net understand this specific logic for dates.  So using the following, you can get what you're looking for:

```
var now = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

[Use DateTime.AddMonth(-1) to get last month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths).

[Use DateTime.AddDays(now.Days * -1 + 1) to get the first of the month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays).

[Use DateTime.DayOfWeek to determine the day and subtract or add days as necessary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you can do is determine the day of the week of the first day of the month last month, take the difference between the day of the week you want and that day of the week, then add 7 * the weeks you want (less one week)...

```
// Let's get the 3rd Friday of last month:

// get starting date
DateTime date = new DateTime();

// get first day of last month
DateTime firstOfLastMonth = date.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-1 * (date.Day + 1));

// subtract out the day of the week (get the previous Sunday, even if it is last month)
DateTime justBeforeMonth = firstOfLastMonth.AddDays((int)firstOfLastMonth.DayOfWeek);

// Add in the DayOfWeek number we are looking for
DateTime firstFridayOfMonth = justBeforeMonth.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Friday);

// if we are still in last month, add a week to get into this month
if (firstFridayOfMonth.Month != date.AddMonth(-1).Month) { firstFridayOfMonth.AddDays(7); }

// add in 2 weeks to get the third week of the month
DateTime thirdFridayOfMonth = firstFridayOfMonth.AddDays(14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with. If the day doesn't exist (e.g. 8th Saturday), GetDate() will return null:

```
{
    DateTime lastMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1);
    DateTime? date = GetDate(lastMonth.Month, lastMonth.Year, DayOfWeek.Thursday, 2);
}

private static DateTime? GetDate(int month, int year, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int which)
{
    DateTime firstOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

    DateTime date;
    for (date = firstOfMonth; date.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek; date = date.AddDays(1))
        ;

    date = date.AddDays(7 * (which - 1));

    return date.Month == month && date.Year == year ? (DateTime?)date : null;
}
```